# Is there a difference between "double val = 1;" and "double val = 1D;"?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a difference between the following two pieces of code?

```
class Test {

    public readonly double Val;

    public Test(bool src) {
        this.Val = src ? 1 : 0;
    }

}

class Test {

    public readonly double Val;

    public Test(bool src) {
        this.Val = src ? 1D : 0D;
    }

}
```

I found that our code base uses the second way of writing.

Comment: Off the top of my head, first one involves a long to double promotion.

Comment: No, it's not. The D extension to a number just makes sure it's really a double. I prefer just to write 1.0 to distinguish it from the integer. But the compiler will recognize that and generate the same code in any way.

Comment: first makes implicit conversion to double, second not makes any conversion.

Comment: Your question title and the question in the body do not match, and the two questions have different answers.

Comment: @Eric Lippert In fact, the body of the question has been edited by other users.

Comment: @srnldai: The code edits were purely for formatting.  They don't change Eric's point.

Comment: @Brian: No, the original poster is correct; the edit changed the meaning of the question, which I did not notice. The original question was "Is there a difference...? **Further,** is there a difference...?", my emphasis.  The removed "Further" indicates that the original poster realized that they were asking *two* questions that might have different answers. That's a bad practice; questions should ideally ask a single question. But the edit makes it seem like the two questions are intended to be the same question, not two different questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two questions here and it is important to note that they have different answers.

> Is there a difference between `double val = 1;` and `double val = 1D;`?

No. The C# compiler recognizes when an integer literal is used in a context where a double is expected and does the type change at compile time, so these two fragments will generate the same code.

> Is there a difference between the following two pieces of code?

```
double Val; 
...    
this.Val = src ? 1 : 0;
---
this.Val = src ? 1D : 0D;
```

Yes. The rule that integer constants are automatically changed to doubles only applies to *constants*, and `src ? ...` is not a *constant*.  The compiler will generate the former as though you wrote:

```
int t;
if (src)
  t = 1;
else
  t = 0;
this.Val = (double)t;
```

And the second as

```
double t;
if (src)
  t = 1D;
else
  t = 0D;
this.Val = t;
```

That is, in the first we choose an integer and then convert it to double, and in the second we choose a double.

FYI: the C# compiler or the jitter are *permitted* to recognize that the first program can be optimized into the second, but I do not know if it actually does so.  The C# compiler *does* sometimes move conversions for *lifted* arithmetic into the bodies of conditionals; I wrote that code some eight years ago now, but I do not recall all of the details.

Answer (score 6):

There *is* a difference in the generated IL code.

This class:

```
class Test1
{
    public readonly double Val;

    public Test1(bool src)
    {
        this.Val = src ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Produces this IL code for the constructor:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Demo.Test1
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .field public initonly float64 Val

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor (
            bool src
        ) cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: ldarg.1
        IL_0008: brtrue.s IL_000d

        IL_000a: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000b: br.s IL_000e

        IL_000d: ldc.i4.1

        IL_000e: conv.r8
        IL_000f: stfld float64 Demo.Test1::Val
        IL_0014: ret
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
class Test2
{
    public readonly double Val;

    public Test2(bool src)
    {
        this.Val = src ? 1d : 0d;
    }
}
```

Produces this IL code for the constructor:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Demo.Test2
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .field public initonly float64 Val

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor (
            bool src
        ) cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: ldarg.1
        IL_0008: brtrue.s IL_0015

        IL_000a: ldc.r8 0.0
        IL_0013: br.s IL_001e

        IL_0015: ldc.r8 1

        IL_001e: stfld float64 Demo.Test2::Val
        IL_0023: ret
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the first version it has to call `conv.r8` to convert an int to a double.

However: (1) The end result is identical and (2) the JIT compiler may well translate both of these to the same machine code.

So the answer is: Yes, there *is* a difference - but not one that you need to worry about.

Personally, I'd go for the second version since that better expresses the programmer's intent, and *may* produce very very slightly more efficient code (depending on what the JIT compiler gets up to).

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, the compiler is smart enough to implicitely do a conversion or not.
However, if you use `var`, you need to write `var val = 42D;` to make sure the variable is a double and not an int.

```
double foo = 1;  // This is a double having the value 1
double bar = 1d; // This is a double having the value 1

var val = 42d;   // This is a double having the value 42
var val2 = 42;   // /!\ This is an int having the value 42 !! /!\
```